# Lubuntu - Black screen after login after updating

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox, lubuntu, login, crash

I have an Lubuntu 18.04 VM that I use for development on my Windows 10 machine. The Lubuntu virtual machine is running on a VirtualBox (version 6.1.62), and with the VirtualBox Addon Tools installed.

Every time I upgrade the kernel (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`), after rebooting the login screen is at 800x600 (or so) resolution. I enter my login credentials without problems, but after clicking on the login button, a black screen appears.

When I'm on the black screen, the virtual machine isn't hanged. It just doesn't do anything. If I move to a virtual tty (`CTRL`+`ALT`+`1`), I can login correctly and run the GUI using `startx`.

Things I tried:

- Uninstalling the `VirtualBoxAddons`: the GUI works correctly, but at 800x600 pixels (usually it runs at the same size of the maximized VirtualBox window). I can't access the shared folders and so.
- Reinstalling the `VirtualBoxAddons` from the command line: it doesn't change anything.
- Reinstalling the `VirtualBoxAddons` from the GUI: it doesn't change anything.

Any idea of what can I do to fix this? And to avoid this problem? Because it happens every time I upgrade the kernel... Maybe should I upgrade to 20.04? I'm not upgrading because the server where I deploy my code it's also an 18.04, but maybe it's time to upgrade all...

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* only had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Comment: FYI: Upgrades from Lubuntu 18.04 LTS are not supported ; ie. see https://lubuntu.me/focal-2-released/ which states "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*"

Comment: @guiverc thank you for your comment! I didn't know that information. Anyway, if I'm not upgrading is because the server is running Ubuntu 18.04 Server (with all the updates), and I want dev & prod environments to be the same. Of course, in the server environment there aren't all the GUI packages...